# Laser_scan_matcher can't find base_link

Tags: navigation, odometry, hokuyo-node, amcl, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings. I am using the following launch file to get odometry from laser_scan_matcher so I can use it with amcl:

```
    <launch>
    <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/skel/test.yaml" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="hokuyo_transformer" type="laser_to_pcl" name="laser_to_pcl"/>
    <node name="hokuyo" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" required="true" output="screen" >
        <param name="frame_id" type="str" value="laser"/> 
        <param name="port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/> 
        <param name="intensity" type="bool" value="false"/>
    </node>

  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />
</launch>
```

But when I run the file I get the following message :

> [ WARN] [1381839319.059787240]:
> Skipping scan [ WARN]
> [1381839320.066850260]: Could not get
> initial transform from base to laser
> frame, "base_link" passed to
> lookupTransform argument target_frame
> does not exist.

However the transform is happenning and is being published since
rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /laser
outputs

```
At time 1381839581.581
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.000]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000]
            in RPY [0.000, -0.000, 0.000]
```

Any idea on what is the matter ? I am currently using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91016/laser_scan_matcher-can%27t-find-base_link/) by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I seem to have solved the problem in the most random way possible but still it may be good to document it.
Trying to fiddle around with the code I got the error :
symbol lookup error:

```
/usr/lib/libgsl.so.0: undefined symbol: cblas_dtrsv
```

Searching, I found that this error is caused by a linker called `libutils-gold`

I sudo apt-get purge'd it, relinked and recompiled and lo and behold everything is working normally (for the time being at least)

Maybe someone should add it to the laser scan matcher documentation to avoid such unecesary frustration

---

Originally posted by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) with karma: 140 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1